# Company Website required for registering as Enterprise App Developer

Tags: applications, developer-program, enterprise

I am trying to register under the Enterprise Developer program but I get a response that the website needs to be working.

Does the website need to be a company name domain or can it be an app name domain?

Answer (score 1):

There are clear requirement details on the Developer sign-up site - [What You Need To Enroll](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/enroll/)

Specifically...

> **A Website**
>   Your organization’s website must be publicly available and the domain name must be associated with your organization.